# Error Installing Scrapy using PyCharm on Windows?

Tags: python, scrapy, pycharm

I'm completely new to Python, however I've watched some basis tutorials and I'm attempting to install Scrapy using PyCharm. When I attempt to install I get the following error code:

command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

- I have installed the 2019 C++ build tools, as well as Visual Studio (fresh install)
- I have uninstalled and removed Python and PyCharm and reinstalled both
- Pip version is up to date and correct according to PyCharm

... I read a solution previously where it said to download the correct version of Twisted, however I'm not sure how to do this through PyCharm, as it would normally install the correct version of Twisted as part of the Scrapy install package.

Additional info on the output code is below (bottom of the output):

*Running setup.py clean for cryptography*
*Failed to build cryptography*

*Failed building wheel for cryptography*
*Could not build wheels for cryptography which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly*

any help would be great!
thanks

Comment: maybe do it normally - using only `pip` without `PyCharm`. OR maybe use [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/) to install Python with some precompiled modules - and it should have Scrapy precompiled.

Comment: see also [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/). There should be precompiled `Scrapy` too.

Comment: Are you using virtual environments?

Comment: I was attempting to, yes - I've been following a tutorial which uses venv created in PyCharm. As an alternative, I managed to get scrapy working using a conda environment through PyCharm (downloaded anaconda and installed using that) - seems to work for now, are there any drawbacks to this?